# Python, compare numbers

Tags: python

I tried to write code as below to compare a serious of numbers.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    nums = numl = input("Enter a number: ")

    if numl == "done" : break

    if smallest == None:
        smallest = nums
    elif smallest > nums:
        smallest = nums
    print(smallest)

    if largest == None:
        largest = numl
    elif largest < numl:
        largest = int(numl)
    print(largest)


print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

[However, it makes the wrong result or even post error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el7tO.jpg)
Can someone help to check it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Assuming you're using Python 3, the value returned by `input` is always a string.  You need to convert it to a number before attempting any numeric operations on it, e.g. `int(s)` or `float(s)`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would request you to post the code with the question rather than an image link.

According to your code, you are taking `input()` which returns `string`, then you are trying to see if a `string` is `>` a `int`

which won't work

you can compare `int` with `int` and `str` with `str`

Comment: Yeah I got it now! Thank you!!